# Calendar reminder background utility not working

Tags: c++, winapi, background-process

I've tried to create a background utility using C++ which functions as a calendar reminder. The program compiles and runs without a hitch, but it doesn't sound an alert, when it is supposed to... Here's the code:

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>
#include<ctime>

char Caption[] = "AshTech EventSentinel";

struct EventFormat
{
    char *notes; // Notes for the event
    int repeat; // Repeat flag (0-No, 1-Daily, 2-Weekly, 3-Monthly, 4-Yearly)
    int day; // Day of week  (0-Sunday, 1-Monday,..., 6-Saturday)
    int hour; // Hour of day (0-23 hours)
    int min; // Minute of hour (0-59 minutes)
    int date; // Date of month (1-31 days)
    int mon; // Month of year (0-January, 1-February,..., 11-December)
    int year; // Year of event
};

void Alert(char*);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
int       nCmdShow)
{
    char *filepath = "C:\\Windows\\EventSentinel_db.esdb";
    ifstream db_in(filepath);

    // If file exists, enter program.
    if(db_in)
    {
        int RecordNum, i;
        string FileRecord;
        i = RecordNum = 0;

        // Calculate number of lines in the file...
        while(getline(db_in, FileRecord))
        if (!FileRecord.empty())
            RecordNum++;

        EventFormat *Event;
        time_t     rawtime;
        struct tm* timeinfo;
        Event = new EventFormat[RecordNum];

        /********* EDITED ********/

        // Initializes all objects created to -1
        for(i=0;i<RecordNum;i++)
        {
            Event[i].date =
            Event[i].day =
            Event[i].hour =
            Event[i].min =
            Event[i].mon =
            Event[i].repeat =
            Event[i].year = -1;
        }
        db_in.seekg(0); // Reposition get pointer at the 0th byte...            
        /*************************/

        // Load struct array.
        while (!db_in.eof())
        {

            // EXCEPTION THROWN IN THIS STATEMENT BELOW...
            db_in.getline(Event[i].notes,','); // Assign input to Event[i].notes until ',' is encountered.

            db_in >> Event[i].repeat;
            switch (Event[i].repeat)
            {
                case 0: // No repeat - single instance.
                {
                    db_in >> Event[i].date;
                    db_in >> Event[i].mon;
                    db_in >> Event[i].year;
                    db_in >> Event[i].hour;
                    db_in >> Event[i].min;
                }break;
                case 1: // Repeat daily
                {
                    db_in >> Event[i].hour;
                    db_in >> Event[i].min;
                }break;             
                case 2: // Repeat weekly
                {
                    db_in >> Event[i].day;
                    db_in >> Event[i].hour;
                    db_in >> Event[i].min;
                }break;             
                case 3: // Repeat monthly
                {
                    db_in >> Event[i].date;
                    db_in >> Event[i].hour;
                    db_in >> Event[i].min;
                }break;             
                case 4: // Repeat yearly
                {
                    db_in >> Event[i].mon;
                    db_in >> Event[i].date;
                    db_in >> Event[i].hour;
                    db_in >> Event[i].min;
                }
            }
        }

        // Close file.
        db_in.close();

        // Main Loop.
        while (1)
        {
            time(&rawtime);
            timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
            for (i = 0; i < RecordNum; i++)
            {
                switch (Event[i].repeat)
                {
                    // No Repeat
                    case 0:
                    {
                        if (
                            timeinfo->tm_year == Event[i].year&&
                            timeinfo->tm_mon == Event[i].mon&&
                            timeinfo->tm_mday == Event[i].date&&
                            timeinfo->tm_hour == Event[i].hour&&
                            timeinfo->tm_min == Event[i].min
                            )
                            Alert(Event[i].notes);
                    }break;
                    // Repeat Daily
                    case 1:
                    {
                        if (
                            timeinfo->tm_hour == Event[i].hour&&
                            timeinfo->tm_min == Event[i].min
                            )
                            Alert(Event[i].notes);
                    }break;
                    // Repeat Weekly
                    case 2:
                    {
                        if (
                            timeinfo->tm_wday == Event[i].day&&
                            timeinfo->tm_hour == Event[i].hour&&
                            timeinfo->tm_min == Event[i].min
                            )
                            Alert(Event[i].notes);
                    }break;
                    // Repeat Monthly
                    case 3:
                    {
                        if (
                            timeinfo->tm_wday == Event[i].date&&
                            timeinfo->tm_hour == Event[i].hour&&
                            timeinfo->tm_min == Event[i].min
                            )
                            Alert(Event[i].notes);
                    }break;
                    // Repeat Yearly
                    case 4:
                    {
                        if (
                            timeinfo->tm_mon == Event[i].mon&&
                            timeinfo->tm_wday == Event[i].date&&
                            timeinfo->tm_hour == Event[i].hour&&
                            timeinfo->tm_min == Event[i].min
                            )
                            Alert(Event[i].notes);
                    }break;
                }
            }
            Sleep(10000);
        }

        delete[] Event;
    }

    // If file doesn't exist, create new file, and exit program.
    else
    {
        ofstream db_new(filepath);
        db_new.close();
        MessageBox(
            NULL,
            "File did not exist. New file has been created. Please add some events to it, for EventSentinel to handle.",
            "EventSentinel - Error detected!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    }
    return 0;
}

void Alert(char* notes)
{
    strcat(notes, "\r\n\n\nPress <ESC> to stop...");
    int KeyPress = -1;
    MessageBox(NULL, notes, Caption, MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    while (KeyPress != VK_ESCAPE)
    {
        if (_kbhit())
            KeyPress = getch;
        Beep(4000, 100);
        Sleep(25);
        Beep(4000, 100);
        Sleep(25);
        Beep(4000, 100);
        Sleep(25);
        Beep(4000, 100);
        Sleep(525);
    }
}
```

Here's a sample input from database file: `TV Show,1 12 00`
where "TV Show" is the reminder itself, 1 stands for 'daily' repeat flag value, so it takes only the hour('12') and the minute('00') into consideration.

Can someone pinpoint the problem here? All corrections, optimizations, suggestions, and constructive criticism greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Constructive criticism #1, dont post a wall of code and minimal details about the problem and expect people to recreate it for themselves. You need a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Right! I'm very sorry! I'm in the process.

Answer (score 1):

```
    while(getline(db_in, FileRecord))
        if (!FileRecord.empty())
            RecordNum++;

    ...

    // Load struct array.
    while (!db_in.eof())
```

The first loop reads the entire file, the second loop reads nothing.

You probably want to `db_in.seekg(0)`.

Comment: Shit! The first loop counts the number of lines to create as much EventFormat objects. Is there any other way? Thanks!

Comment: Brainwave! Can I simply add a seekp(0,ios::beg)? Will that work?

Comment: @AnandS Yes, that rewinds the file back to the beginning. Alternatively, you could consider using a `std::vector` to hold your `Event`s, that way you don't have to worry about allocating the right size.